# A specific fix in the bst file needed

Tags: abbrvnat.bst

I am working with a \documentclass{article} document in LaTeX.

This is an excerpt from my bst file:

```
  FUNCTION {begin.bib}    
   { preamble$ empty$    
      'skip$    
      { preamble$ write$ newline$ }    
    if$    
    "\begin{thebibliography}{}" write$ newline$    
   }    
  EXECUTE {begin.bib}    
  EXECUTE {init.state.consts}    
  ITERATE {call.type$}    
  FUNCTION {end.bib}    
   { newline$    
      "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$    
   }    
  EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

My LaTeX file ends with:

```
 \bibliographystyle{sean}    
 \bibliography{asa_bib}    
 \nocite{*}    
 \end{document}
```

And this is the outcome:

---

[image]

---

with a vertical gap between the section title and the first reference in the list.

Could someone kindly tell me how to alter the bst file, to remove the gap?
/ My attempts to directly insert \vspace{-10pt} into the LaTeX file failed. /

This is the first time in my life that I have to mess with a bst file. So I would appreciate a simple and detaild fool-proof answer. Ideally, a corrected version of the above bst commands. Thank you.

Just in case, here are the macros:

```
 \documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}    
 \pagestyle{empty}    
 \textwidth=5.5in    
 \textheight=8.50truein    
 \baselineskip=5pt    
 \parindent=12pt    
    \usepackage{makeidx}   %  For indexing    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{epsfig}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{natbib}    
\usepackage{enumitem}     
 \usepackage[dvips]{color}    

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{7}{5}{4}    
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}    

\font\sevennrr=ptmr at 7pt              
\font\eightnrr=ptmr at 8pt              
\font\ninenrr=ptmr at 9pt              
\font\tennrr=ptmr                     
\font\elevennrr=ptmr at 11pt           
\font\twelvenrr=ptmr at 12pt           
\font\eightnrri=ptmri at 8pt       
\font\ninenrri=ptmri at 9pt        
\font\tennrri=ptmri                
\font\eightrb=ptmb at 8pt          
\font\ninerb=ptmb at 9pt           
\font\tennrb=ptmb                  
\font\sevenarbi=phvbo at 7pt        
\font\sevenari=phvro at 7pt          
\font\twelvearbi=phvbo at 12pt      
\font\astrosym=astrosym at 20pt        
      
%-----Section L page numbers        
       
\def\pageJPLint{L5}        % JPL integration description     
\def\pageJPLdes{L5}        % Description about JPL DE405/LE405    
\def\pageTimeScales{L3}    % timescales    
    
%-----Page Numbers: Section A    
    
\def\pagemnphA{A1}         % Moon phases    
\def\pageoccns{A2}         % Lunar occultations    
\def\pagegeoph{A3}         % Geocentric phenomena    
\def\pagehelph{A3}         % Heliocentric phenomena    
\def\pagemagmv{A4}         % Mercury & Venus elongations and magnitudes     
\def\pagemphen{A4}         % Minor planet phenomena    
\def\pagemgpl{A5}          % Mars - Neptune elongations and magnitudes    
\def\pagempmag{A5}         % Selected Dwarf & Minor planet magnitudes    
\def\pagesmags{A4--A5}      % Planet elongations and magnitudes    
\def\pagesdiary{A9--A11}   % Diary of Phenomena    
\def\pagersexpl{A12}       % Riseset explanation    
\def\pagersex{A13}         % Rise set examples    
\def\pageseclexpl{A78--A83}% Eclipse explanation    
    
%-----Section B page numbers    
    
\def\pageJD{B3}            % Julian Date    
\def\pagesDays{B4--B5}     % Days in the year    
\def\pageTimenotation{B6}  % Notation for timescales    
\def\pagesTimRelat{B6--B12}%    
\def\pageERAf{B8}          % ERA formulae    
\def\pageGMST{B8}          % Page for GMST formulae    
\def\pageGAST{B9}          % Page for GAST formulae    
\def\pageERAf{B8}          %    
\def\pageLHA{B11}          % Relationship between GHA & LHA    
\def\pagesUST{B13--B20}    % Universal & Sidereal Times, tabular pages    
\def\pagesERA{B21--B24}    % UT and Earth Rotation Angle, tabular pages    
\def\pagesBPNCtoI{B30--B45}% Both BPN and Celestial to Intermediate matricies.    
\def\pagexys{B46}          % Page for the definition of X & Y    
\def\pageFB{B50}           % Frame bias    
\def\pageapproxprec{B54}   % Reduction for precession - approximate formulae    
\def\pageBPN{B56}          % Combined bias precession and nutation matrix    
\def\pagesEarthXYZ{B76-B83}% Position and velocity of Earth, tabular pages    
\def\pagesexppol{B87-B92}  % Pole star explanation and tables    
\def\pagesTimRelat{B6--B12}% Timescales and the repationships between them    
    
%-----Section D page numbers    
    
\def\pagesDfstfive{D1--D5}  % Moon, first 5 pages before tables    
\def\pageMoonEl{D2}         % Moon elements (Omega, I)    
\def\pageMoonlib{D5}        % Lunar Librations    
\def\pagesMoonapp{D6--D20}  % Moon's apparent coordinates   
\def\pagesMoonphy{D7--D21}  % Moon's physical coordinates    
\def\pageMoonlow{D22}       % Moon, low-precision & notes and formulae    
    
%-----Section K page numbers    
    
\def\pagesconsts{K6--K7}   % Seclected Astronomical Constants    
\def\pageconstsa{K6}        % Astronomical Constants IAU values 1st page K6    
\def\pageconstsb{K7}        % Astronomical Constants IAU values 2nd page K7    
\def\pagesDeltaT{K8--K9}   % Delta T pages    
\def\pageDeltaT{K9}        % Current years Delta T    
\def\pagexypm{K10}         % XY for polar motion    
\def\pagesITRF{K11--K13}   % Reduction of Terrestiral coordinates    
\def\pagesJDsex{K2--K5}    % Table Julian Dates, explanation and examples    
\def\pagePlanetRadii{K7}   % WG CCRE, planetary radii    
    
%-----Section Z page numbers    
    
\def\pageWebLinks{x}       % Page with all the http:// links    
    
%------Journal Commands for the text - may not need these.    
    
\newcommand{\AJ}{\tennrri Astron. Jour.}    
\newcommand{\AnA}{\tennrri Astron. Astrophys.}    
\newcommand{\AnAs}{\tennrri Astron. Astrophys. Supp. Ser.}    
\newcommand{\ApJ}{\tennrri Astrophys. Jour.}    
\newcommand{\ApJs}{\tennrri Astrophys. Jour. Supp. Ser.}    
\newcommand{\CM}{\tennrri Celest. Mech.}    
\newcommand{\MNRAS}{\tennrri Mon. Not. Roy. Astron. Soc.}    
\newcommand{\PASP}{\tennrri Pub. Astron. Soc. Pac.}    
%    
%------General Defs  --------------%    
%    
\def\AT{\hbox{\rm AT}}            % AT    
\def\DeltaT{\hbox{$\Delta T$}}    % Delta T    
\def\TT{\hbox{\rm TT}}            % TT    
\def\TAI{\hbox{\rm TAI}}          % TAI    
\def\UT{\hbox{\rm UT}}            % UT    
\def\UTC{\hbox{\rm UTC}}          % UTC    
\def\refs{\frenchspacing}         % Ignore space implications of punctuation    
%    
\newcommand{\opcit}{\tennrri op.cit.}    
\newcommand{\ea}{\tennrri et al.}    
\newcommand{\eg}{{\tennrri e.g.}}    
\newcommand{\ie}{{\tennrri i.e.}}    
\newcommand{\asa}{\tennrri The Astronomical Almanac}    
\newcommand{\asao}{\tennrri The Astronomical Almanac Online}    
\newcommand{\asaoUS}{https://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/asa.html}    
\newcommand{\asaoUK}{https://asa.hmnao.com}    
\newcommand{\Teph}{T$_\mathrm{eph}$~}    
\newcommand{\Tephns}{T$_\mathrm{eph}$}    
\def\GMS{\hbox{\it GM\/}_{\mathrm S}}    
%-----Define unit commands    
\newcommand{\degree}{\raisebox{1pt}{$^{{\circ}}$~}}    
\newcommand{\degreens}{\raisebox{1pt}{$^{{\circ}}$}}    
\newcommand{\degreedot}{$^{\circ}\!\!.$}    
\newcommand{\seclittle}{$^\mathrm{s}$}    
\newcommand{\secdot}{$^{\mathrm s}\!\!.$}    
\newcommand{\hrslittle}{$^{\mathrm{h}}$}    
\newcommand{\hrsdot}{\hbox{\hrslittle}\kern -3pt}    
\newcommand{\arcmin}{\hbox{$^{\prime}$}}    
\newcommand{\arcsecdot}{\hbox{$^{\prime\prime}\!\!\!.\,$}}    
%-------Commands for the box   
\def\dotfill{\leaders\hbox{\kern.033333pt.\kern.033333pt}\hfill}   
\newcommand{\WWW}{\lower0.2ex\hbox{\raise1.0ex\hbox{W}\kern-0.1em \raise0.5ex\hbox{W}\kern-0.1em W}}    
\newcommand{\asaoUSB}{\ninerb https://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/asa.html}     
\newcommand{\asaoUKB}{\ninerb http://asa.hmnao.com}    
\newcommand{\tAAO}{\ninenrri The Astronomical Almanac Online}     

\defcitealias{asa_url}{[1]}              
\defcitealias{novas_url}{[2]}           
\defcitealias{sofa_url}{[3]}             
\defcitealias{hpiers_url}{[4]}           
\defcitealias{pubs_url}{[6]}             
\defcitealias{nist_url}{[7]}             
\defcitealias{iota_url}{[8]}             
\defcitealias{sheppard_url}{[9]}         
\defcitealias{jacobson_url}{[10]}        
\defcitealias{saturnian_url}{[11]}       
\defcitealias{uranian_rings_url}{[12]}       
\defcitealias{iaupluto_url}{[13]}        
\defcitealias{horizons_url}{[14]}        
\defcitealias{smallbod_url}{[15]}        
\defcitealias{mpc_dwarf_url}{[16]}       
\defcitealias{NSFA_url}{[17]}            
\defcitealias{orbits_url}{[18]}          
\defcitealias{wds_url}{[19]}             
\defcitealias{eso_url}{[20]}             
\defcitealias{iers_url}{[21]}     
\defcitealias{mpc_url}{[22]}     
\defcitealias{ITRF_url}{[23]}           
\hyphenation{serv-ices plan-et-o-gra-phic ephem-erides ephem-er-is WGC-CRE arc-minute}    
% Page format    
\paperwidth = 504 pt    
\paperheight = 720 pt    
\textwidth = 396 pt    
\oddsidemargin = 9 pt    
\evensidemargin= -42 pt    
\topmargin = -15 pt    
\headheight = 9 pt    
\headsep = 16 pt    
\textheight=585 pt    
% Page header format    
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\fancyhead{}    
\fancyfoot{}    
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\twelvenrr L\thepage}    
\fancyhead[C]{\twelvenrr NOTES AND REFERENCES}    
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}    
% Format section and sub-section headers    
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontseries{b}\selectfont\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}    
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{8pt}    
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\itshape\filcenter}{}{0pt}{}    
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{8pt}{8pt}    
% Format the table of contents     
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}     
\usepackage{titletoc}     
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{}{}{}
              {\contentsmargin{15pt}\titlerule*[1pc]{.....} L\hspace{-9.5pt}\contentspage}[\vspace{-0.5pt}]     
\titlecontents{subsection}[14pt]{}{}{}
              {\contentsmargin{15pt}\titlerule*[1pc]{.....} L\hspace{-9.5pt}\contentspage}[\vspace{-0.5pt}]             
    
% No separation of items in a list.    
    
\setlist{nosep}
```

Comment: it's almost certainly unrelated to the code shown, but you have not provided enough code to reproduce the problem so it's hard to help. I would guess your document is using `\flushbottom` and there is some large unbreakable thing at the top of the next page, and the space afer the heading is the only stretchy glue on this page.

Comment: the space between `[` and `1` also looks weird, is that intentional?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your response. The space between [ and 1 can be fixed. You said: "there is some large unbreakable thing at the top of the next page," If you mean the LaTeX file, there is nothing on the next page. This is the end of file:   \bibliographystyle{sean}
 \bibliography{asa_bib}
 \nocite{*}

 \end{document}

And there is no \flushbottom command in the document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, there is nothing to add from the LaTeX file here. Should I add more of the bst file, perhaps?

Comment: well the spacing is almost certainly due to tex macros not the bst file, but as you show no usable code it is really impossible to guess. I made one guess (that explains 90% of large space after section questions) but as you show, guesses can be wrong. You need to provide more clues or I think the question will end up being closed as "needs details or clarity"

Comment: specifically, I assume the space between  **References** and the start of the reference list is produced by the start code of the `thebibliography` environment which is defined to do `\section*{References}... some macros ... \begin{list}....`  and ... some macros` are making the space. So the problem is in tex code, not bst code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have just in case added the macros into my question. The two commands prior to \bibliographystyle{sean} are:    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
 and
    \section*{}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} . I have now commented out both these commands - but, amazingly, nothing changed at all.  Looks like this title **References** and the subsequent gap are somehow encoded into the bst file or in the macros

Comment: eek no latex file should have `\font\sevennrr=ptmr at 7pt` since the latex font selection scheme was introduced in 1990 where did that come from????.  You have now shown a lot of code but none of it related to your problem. You should be able to supply a small self contained document without all those unrelated definitions  that produces the output shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You may be right in that the problem is unrelated to the bst. I have just tried the ordinary plainnat.bst, and the outcome was the same. [As for the changed fonts -- they work perfectly.]

Comment: for some definition of "work" they will of course select a font but they completely break latex's font handling, they are written in the style of latex2.09 and ignore 30 years of tex development, but also they are unrelated to the question. You need to post code that produces the output that you are asking about. No one can help if you post unrelated bst code then unrelated tex code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  This just a text with citations. For example, the citation of the first reference looks in the text as \citetalias{asa_url} , the meaning of asa_url explained in the macros that I presented in my question:  \defcitealias{asa_url}{[1]}

Comment: if it's just a text with citations, why for example does it have `\usepackage{epsfig}` (which I wrote in 1993 as an explicitly legacy compatibility package for documents from the 1980s) and why does it have `\usepackage[dvips]{color} ` so it has to be used with latex not pdflatex  and  `\font\sevennrr=ptmr at 7pt  ` breaks all latex font handling, it will load a font but latex will not know it is there so `\itshape` won't make it italic, `\bfseries` won't make it bold, but none of this is related to your question, and you have still not provided an example, sorry we can't help.

Comment: Hey @Michael_1812, welcome to TeX.SX! Can you try to minimalize your example, i.e. strip away stuff to the point where the error still shows up?

Comment: @Ruben That was a scan. I don't know how to squeeze it. Could you please advise me how to do this?